# Como Adicionar um IF (Condition) no onEndReached em React-Native?

Tags: react-native

Tenho uma `flatList` que carrega 20 registros por vez, quando chega no final da lista, o componente `onEndReached` chama meu método que carrega mais 20, e assim carrega até trazer todos, porém, quando acaba meus registros, ele ainda continua tentando procurar, oque diminui o desempenho do meu App.
Tentei adiconar um IF no `onEndReached`, porem como é dentro de um flatList não consegui fazer isso.
alguém tem uma solução para isso?

Exemplo do meu Código:

```
<FlatList
        data={this.state.data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <ListItem
            title={item.conta}
            subtitle={item.saldo}

          />
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item) => {
          return item.id;
        }}
        onEndReached={this.makeRemoteRequest}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}

      />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o if ternário nesse caso:

```
onEndReached={this.makeRemoteRequest == condição ? Se sim : Se não}
```

Espero ter ajudado amigo.

Comment: Show, funcionou. Obrigado pela ajuda Maycon.

Comment: Amigo se você puder pontuar a resposta, ficarei muito agradecido.